How to append columns when writing to a data file
I have a data of form
xtbl = Table[x, {x, 1, 100, 1}];
F1tbl = Map[#^2 &, xtbl];
F2tbl = Map[#^3 &, xtbl];

and I can write it into a file
file = OpenWrite["test.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm, PageWidth -> Infinity];
Do[Write[file, xtbl[[i]], "     ",
   F1tbl[[i]], "     ",
   F2tbl[[i]], "     "
], {i, 1, 100}];
Close[file]

This gives me a nice format that I like.
Now let us imagine I have numerous such functions like F1tbl, F2tbl ... and they are computationally intensive.
I would like to write them to the file as each of them finishes computing, i.e. something like
xtbl = Table[x, {x, 1, 100, 1}];
(* Write a first column to the test.dat file*)
file = OpenWrite["test.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm, PageWidth -> Infinity];
Do[Write[file, xtbl[[i]], "     "], {i, 1, 100}];
Close[file]
(****)
F1tbl = Map[#^2 &, xtbl];
(* code that adds F1 column to the test.dat file *)
F2tbl = Map[#^3 &, xtbl];
(* code that adds F1 column to the test.dat file *)

Naively using OpenAppend , like here
file = OpenAppend["test.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm, PageWidth -> Infinity];
Do[Write[file, F1tbl[[i]], "     "], {i, 1, 100}];
Close[file]

does not help me since it just appends stuff to the end of the file, i.e. it adds rows.
Is there a way to add columns to the file?

Why don't you just write out the transposed version of the data? Then each column gets appended as a row in the file. When all computations are done, you can transpose it back if you wish.

Tnx, sure, this would be an option; equivalently I could export each data set individually and then restructure the data later, or equivalently just hold it in memory and output at the end... however, I was hoping there would exist a solution that would do exactly what I wanted. Indeed, I've been using various of these alternative versions for ages and now finally decided to explore if there is a way to do it this way.
